# Forloop python decrement behaviour when equal to a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x

When the num_products drops to 300, the level should be resupplied by 700.

But in my below code, the level is never equal to exactly 300, it drops below 300, then is incremented by 700.  (If I change "if num_products <= 300" to "==300", it does not increment by 700 at all)

How can I increment by 700 when it drops to exactly 300?

```
num_products = 1000
revenue = 0

for day in range(0, 62):
    num_products -= 36
    revenue += 599
    if num_products <= 300:
        num_products += 700
print("number of products: ", num_products)
```

Comment: `if num_products == 300`???

Comment: Since it is never equal to 300, you need to do some maths.

Comment: Perhaps you could decrease the 'num_products' by 28 each time

Answer (score 1):

When the level drops below 300, just set it to exactly 1000, since that's what you would get if you increased by 700 when it hits 300 exactly.

```
if num_products <= 300:
    num_products = 1000
```